Quick filter bar customization in Thunderbird 128.3 Nebula
Anyone who can suggest me how to customize the quick filter bar in order to retake the appearance of Thunderbird version 102.5. I'd like to restore it in Thunderbird 128.3 but even if I tried to check and read my forum, I didn't find any viable resolution.
I hate both filter text filed on the left other than ctrl+shift+k in the filter text field.
I add a couple of images to explain better my frustration.






